# Is there a built-in constant for the weekdays in English in base R?

Tags: r

Is there a built-in constant for the weekdays in English in base R or in lubridate, like `month.name` for the names of the month. I am new to R. I can type them but I guess there might be a better/right way to print them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
#Date
weekdays(seq(as.Date('2020-12-01'),as.Date('2020-12-07'),length.out = 7))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   
[7] "Monday"
```

Or this:

```
#Date2
format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-12-07'),by='1 month'),'%B')
```

Output:

```
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"     
 [7] "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

And maybe the fastest way:

```
#Code2
levels(lubridate::wday(Sys.Date(), label=TRUE,abbr=FALSE))
```

Output:

```
[1] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[7] "Saturday"
```

Comment: Is there's way to print them sequentially i.e. "Monday", "Tuesday" ... or every time I need the sequence I need to input dates in ```weekdays(seq(as.Date('2020-11-30'),as.Date('2020-12-06'),length.out = 7))```? I wish there was an easier way.

Comment: @Sanjiv You are right, that is a practical way, the you can store in a vector and use for other tasks or code you have. Hope that helped!

Comment: @Sanjiv I have added another option for you using `lubridate`, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Duck, it did. Somehow I am not able to upvote the answer, probably due to lack of enough reputation. I still wish there was constant in the base R, would be huge timesaver for many.

Answer (score 0):

the `wday` function in `lubridate` allows you to print out weekdays in any given locale without having to change system settings.

```
levels(lubridate::wday(1, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, week_start = 1, locale = "en"))
```

You can change parameters to your liking, e.g. `locale` or `week_start`.